# Define the mysql password in environment variable with zend

Tags: zend-framework

I would like to save my sql login/password in my virtualhost (to avoid to be pushed with git) and get it with environment variable but my login/password are saved in a file.ini where I can't call environment variable...

Where can I define my SQL login/password in Zend with environment variable ?

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
SetEnv MYSQL_PWD "fd456fds45bdf"
```

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Zend_Config You can use constants(environment variables) in config files.

Example

```
database.password = MYSQL_PWD
```

Comment: It's ok : define( 'MYSQL_PWD', getenv('MYSQL_PWD') );